# Alias accepting variables from the result of evaluation

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, alias, command-substitution

I was trying to define an alias that helps me to cd to the directory that is created most recently, and I'm using the following in my .bashrc:

```
alias cdlatest="latestdir=$(ls -td -- */|head -n 1); cd $latestdir"
```

But this alias only works once. If I change to a new directoy, it still tries to cd to the last directory. It seems becaue the variable `$(ls -td -- */|head -n 1)` is only evaluated once from the start. How to fix this?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to make this a script? Why does it need to be an alias? I suspect, but haven't found a reference yet, that expressions aren't re-evaluated by the alias mechanism.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13260969/prevent-bash-alias-from-evaluating-statement-at-shell-start

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your double quotes around the alias definition to single and you"re good to go.

```
alias cdlatest='latestdir=$(ls -td -- */|head -n 1); cd $latestdir'
```

However, I'd suggest a few streamlining:

```
alias cdlatest='cd "$(\ls -td -- */|head -n 1)"'
```

where we do away the intermediate variable "$latestdir", quote the results of the command evaluation $(...), and use an unaliased form of ls.

But you need to remember, that this will not handle files with newlines in their names.